# how to solve ERR! code node_debug_log?

Tags: node.js

[image]

> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   npm ERR!     npm bugs slacky-slack
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls slacky-slack
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
>   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:

Comment: Did you try upgrading your npm? "npm install -g npm"

Comment: yes, i tried. but it's not working